# Always return false when i authenticate an user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I authenticating an user in my application, even with the right credentials , it returns false. Here is my User registration controller

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
$user = new User();

    $password = str_random(10);

    $password_hash = Hash::make($password);

    $active_hash = Hash::make(str_random(128));

    $new_user = $user->create([
        'first_name'=>$request->first_name,
        'last_name'=>$request->last_name,
        'email'=>$request->email,
        'telephone'=>$request->fone,
        'password'=>$password_hash,
        'active_hash'=>$active_hash,
    ]);

    $new_user->permissions()->create(UserPermission::$default);
    //send email to the user
    Mail::send('admin.emails.auth.new_user',['new_user'=>$new_user,'active_hash'=>$active_hash,'password'=>$password],function($message) use ($new_user){
        $message->to($new_user->email)
                ->from('lilgaetan88@gmail.com','Pacal Gaetan')
                ->subject("Activate your account");
    });

    return redirect()->route('home')->with('Success',"mail sent");

}
```

The user receive the email with the $passowrd = str_random(10), he then copy it and paste in the password field of the login form

LoginController:

```
    public function postLogin(LoginRequest $request){



 $remember = ($request->has('remember')) ? true : false;
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;

    $auth = Auth::attempt([
        'email'=>$email,
        'password'=>$password,
        'active'=>1
    ],$remember);

    dd($auth);

    if($auth) {

        return redirect()->intended('/accueil');

    }else{
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('fail',"User not found");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code.

**First**, you don't hash your password when you create a user. It needs to be done due to security reasons. It also will break the authentication if password stored in the database is not a proper hash, as Laravel uses **bcrypt hasher** internally to verify passwords.

In your store method you need to pass to **create()** method

```
'password' => Hash::make($password),
```

instead of

```
'password'=>$password,
```

**Secondly**, **Auth::attempt()** requires a plain-text password to be passed. You are hashing the value user provided before calling this method, that's why it doesn't match.

Comment: I think I see what you saying. But I want to generate a random password to user via E-mail when I register one. How to get the non hashed value of that password? @jedzrej.kurylo

Comment: Send user the plaintext password, but store the hashed password in the database

Comment: And hashes are by definition not unhashable

Comment: I edit my code. I stored the hashed value of $password in the database and sent the plain password to the user. I still don't know why I got false when I dd($auth)

Comment: Can you update the question with current code? It still passes hashed password to attempt()

Comment: i did edit the code already with the updated one @jedrzej.kurylo

Comment: Make also sure that the user is activated. If not, auth::attempt() will return false

Comment: The user is activated. Active is 1 in the db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87065/discussion-between-jedrzej-kurylo-and-gaetan-sobze).

Comment: OK. Can we chat in SO?